# RadioButtonList remove all contents and refill using java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

To clear listbox using javascript the following Works fine

```
document.getElementById("<%= Listbox.ClientID %>").selectedIndex = -1;
document.getElementById("<%= Listbox.ClientID %>").options.length = 0;
```

but to clear RadioButtonList the following did not work, is there a way

```
document.getElementById("<%= RadioButtonList.ClientID %>").selectedIndex = -1;
document.getElementById("<%= RadioButtonList.ClientID %>").options.length = 0;
```

I need to know - 
Using Javascript how to remove the whole contents of RadioButtonList and refill with different items

Comment: Is the "RadioButtonList" really a select element? Basicly, [your code works as it is](https://jsfiddle.net/hg3fkwca/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to remove the complete content in the table LawGroupTable

`document.getElementById('LawGroupTable').innerHTML="";`

To remove inner table alone:

`document.getElementById('RLst_CharGroup').innerHTML="";`

You have to refill it like below

`document.getElementById('RLst_CharGroup').innerHTML = '<tbody><tr><td><input name="RLst_CharGroup" id="RLst_CharGroup_0" type="radio" value="a">' +
            '<label for="RLst_CharGroup_0">1</label></td></tr><tr><td><input name="RLst_CharGroup" id="RLst_CharGroup_1" type="radio" value="b">' +
            '<label for="RLst_CharGroup_1">2</label></td></tr><tr><td><input name="RLst_CharGroup" id="RLst_CharGroup_2" type="radio" value="c">' +
            '<label for="RLst_CharGroup_2">3</label></td></tr>';`

Comment: This is working good to remove the complete contents the remaining part is to refill the radiobuttonlist    (RLst_CharGroup)

Comment: Thanks
                        
Adding an item to asp: listbox I use the following
                        .....
                        var newOption = new Option(); 
                        newOption.text = varFromListBox.options[i].text;
                        varToListBox.options[varToListBox.length] = newOption;
                        .....
I am assuming RadioButtonListBox behaves like a listbox
But the way you are suggesting to add new items gives impression that RadioButtonListBox is not like Listbox
In other words Can I add an item to listbox using traditional select

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('.checkboxlistid9').removeAttr('checked');` this jQuery for uncheck all radio List.

Comment: The question is about Javascript not JQuery

Comment: thanks for the help - uncheck is not required      what is wanted is remove all contents of RadioButtonList and replace with other items using javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use `removeAttribute` in javascript like this:

`document.getElementById("<%= RadioButtonList.ClientID %>").removeAttribute('checked');`

Comment: thanks for the help - removing checked is not required      what is wanted is remove all contents of RadioButtonList and replace with other items

Comment: Can you share the radio button with its content please? If its content is HTML then  use ``document.getElementById("<%= RadioButtonList.ClientID %>").innerHTML = "";``

Answer (score 0):

The following is part of the render of adding items to radiobuttonlist

```
        <table width="100%" align="right" id="LawGroupTable" style="margin-top: -10px; display: none;" bgcolor="#666666">
              <tbody>
                    <tr>
                          <td>
                                <table id="RLst_CharGroup">
                                      <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                            <td>
                                            <input name="RLst_CharGroup" id="RLst_CharGroup_0" type="radio" value="a">
                                            <label for="RLst_CharGroup_0">1</label>
                                            </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                            <td>
                                            <input name="RLst_CharGroup" id="RLst_CharGroup_1" type="radio" value="b">
                                            <label for="RLst_CharGroup_1">2</label>
                                            </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                            <td>
                                            <input name="RLst_CharGroup" id="RLst_CharGroup_2" type="radio" value="c">
                                            <label for="RLst_CharGroup_2">3</label>
                                            </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                </table>
                          </td>
                    </tr>
              </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Please add the code to your question, answers are for answers only. You can find the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60648614/edit) below the question.